# I want to convert this foreach loop to a LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am not an great at linq by any means but I usually have no issues with a problem of this sort. I want to convert this foreach statement to a LINQ statement:

```
var existingKeys = new List<int>();
foreach (var taskKey in request.Keys)
        {
             existingKeys.AddRange(_context.WebTaskGroups
                 .Where(x => x.TaskGroupNameKey == key && x.TaskKey == taskKey)
                 .Select(x => x.TaskGroupNameKey));
        }
```

I thought this would do it:

```
var existingKeys = request.Keys.ForEach(taskKey => _context.WebTaskGroups
        .Where(x => x.TaskGroupNameKey == key && x.TaskKey == taskKey)
        .Select(x => x.TaskGroupNameKey));
```

That apparently returns a void not a list...
This:

```
  var existingKeys = request.Keys.Select(taskKey => 
            _context.WebTaskGroups
            .Where(x => x.TaskGroupNameKey == key && x.TaskKey == taskKey)
            .Select(keys => keys.TaskGroupNameKey));
```

Gives me an "IEnumerable<IQueryable<int>>. So what is the secret sauce that I am missing here?

Comment: Assuming you're in Visual Studio, Resharper (a code quality plugin) is actually fairly adept at identifying loops that can be converted to LINQ statements.

Comment: @Ellesedil I am using resharper and usually it gives me the code I want. For some reason on this particular foreach it doesn't help.

Comment: Turning an `IEnumerable<IQueryable<int>>` into an `IEnumerable<int>` should be doable with a `SelectMany` instead of the first Select.

Comment: Fundimentially you're performing N queries, one for each key. You shouldn't do that; you should perform *one* query to get all of the items you want.  Performing all of those round trips to a database is particularly problematic.

Comment: @Servy I agree with your statement. I am rewriting a VB.NET app where this is how they handled it. I was going to refactor after I got the call working the first time.

Comment: @Robert Why spend a bunch of time trying to get a solution working when you know that you're just going to be throwing that work away and doing something entirely different?

Comment: @Servy In this instance the solution for many is not far off of looping through individually. I couldn't get the current statement correct so that I could figure out how to optimize it.

Comment: @Robert What you started with *already worked*.  It's not like you didn't have a working solution.  Using LINQ to try to remove the loop that you have in no way changes the semantics of the code, it's purely aesthetic.  Changing the code to do one query instead of N is actually a semantic change.

Comment: The secret sauce is indeed [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.100).aspx) (just replace `Keys.Select` with it), but I second that you should optimize this instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't be performing N database queries in the first place.  Using LINQ to perform those N queries instead of a `foreach` loop doesn't fix that core problem.

You need to re-conceptualize your query so that you have just one query that gets all of the data that you need.  In this case that means getting all of the items that match your *collection* of keys rather than trying to match a single key and then performing N of those queries.

```
var requestedKeys = request.Keys;
var existingKeys = _context.WebTaskGroups
                 .Where(x => x.TaskGroupNameKey == key && 
                     requestedKeys.Contains(x.TaskKey))
                 .Select(x => x.TaskGroupNameKey))
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: +1 for the notification about the number of queries !

Comment: So what advantages are there to reassigning the keys property before using it in a query?

Comment: @Robert Some query providers will work properly without you needing to do that, some won't, so I did so as I wasn't sure what query provider you were using.

Comment: This may be a dumb question but is the "Query Provider" a reference to the ORM I am using?

Comment: Okay, got it I am using EF.

Answer (score 1):

```
var existingKeys = request
    .SelectMany(r => r.Keys)
    .SelectMany(tk =>
        _context.WebTaskGroups
            .Where(x.TaskGroupNameKey == key && x.TaskKey == tk)
            .Select(x => x.TaskGroupNameKey))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var existingKeys = _context.WebTaskGroups
             .Where(x => x.TaskGroupNameKey == key && request.Keys.Contains(x.TaskKey))
             .Select(x => x.TaskGroupNameKey)
             .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

ForEach return a void: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx

ForEch: Performs the specified action on each element of the List.

So what to do, is for each item in the list of request.Keys to perform the action to add to the list of existingKeys.

For example:

```
request.Keys.ForEach(taskKey => 
         existingKeys.AddRange(_context.WebTaskGroups
             .Where(x => x.TaskGroupNameKey == key && x.TaskKey == taskKey)
             .Select(x => x.TaskGroupNameKey));
```